# How to define Objective-C lightweight generic for Array of Arrays of NSNumbers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, swift, generics

I have an object with a property of `NSArray` that contains other `NSArray`s of `NSNumber`s. I've added a lightweight generic to the property definition in the header file like so:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) NSArray<NSArray *> *myArray;
```

The generated Swift interface shows:

```
public var myArray: [[AnyObject]] { get }
```

Is there a way that I can further mark up my property declaration to indicate that this is actually `[[NSNumber]]`? The compiler gets upset with me when I try `NSArray<NSArray *<NSNumber *>> *myArray;` or `NSArray<NSArray *><NSNumber *> *myArray;`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) NSArray<NSArray<NSNumber *> *> *myArray;
```

All the stars have move to the left.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! I had star-blindness.